# usage of personal pronoun in "not only--but also"

Tags: personal-pronouns

> 1. Not only his friends but also John did not attend **his** classes.
> 2. Not only his friends but also John did not attend **their** classes.

Which personal pronoun is suitable, his or their?

Comment: Just try using the information given in your example to answer the question ***Who** didn't attend class?* It should be pretty obvious your response must be some kind of ***plural***, no matter exactly *how* you phrase it. Not only does John have multiple friends, but also we know that John himself has to be included in the total, *as well as* those friends.

Comment: Yeah @FumbleFingers can't downvote your comment. How convenient for you. But not necessarily helpful to the learner.

Comment: @Fumble using *their* is ambiguous; you could be saying John also didn't attend *their* (=not his own) classes.

Comment: @Alan Carmack: To me, OP's example is an unbelievably non-idiomatic thing to say anyway, and messing about with ***his/their*** can't save it. But note that you can't use "possessive singular they" when the subject is a single ***named*** individual. No-one would say ***John doesn't know their ass from their elbow.***

Comment: It doesn't strike me as at all unidiomatic.

Comment: Which classes were skipped?  The first sentence suggests that all skipped classes were John's classes.  The second suggests that John and his friends skipped all of their classes, probably including classes that John himself doesn't take.  If John takes Am. Lit. and Trig, while a friend takes Am. Lit. and Calc, I have to wonder how empty the calculus classroom might be.

Answer (score 2):

*Not only --- but also ---* falls under [correlative conjunctions](http://speakspeak.com/resources/english-grammar-rules/conjunctions/correlative). Others include include *Either ... or*, *neither ... nor*.

Oft-suggested advice in cases like these is to match the pronoun with the closest noun, thus use ***his***. One reason is because if you use *their*, as in your second sentence, then a straightforward reading means that John also did not attend *their* classes, and the sentence tells us nothing about John attending his own classes.

> When you use correlative conjunctions, be careful about pronoun agreement.
>
> If you connect two antecedents with a correlative conjunction, the second one must agree with the pronoun that follows.
>
> Neither Yolanda nor the cousins expressed **their** disappointment when blind Aunt Sophie set down the plate of burnt hamburgers.
>
> Neither the cousins nor Yolanda expressed **her** disappointment when blind Aunt Sophie set down the plate of burnt hamburgers.

([Grammar Bytes](http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/correlativeconjunction.htm))

> When two words are joined by *or, either…or, neither…nor, not only…but also*, **the pronoun agrees with the noun closer to it**.
>
> Either the students or the teacher will bring his laptop to the presentation.
>
> Either the teacher or the students will bring their laptops to the presentation.
>
> Not only the teacher but also the students were reading their books.
>
> **Not only the students but also the teacher was reading her book.**

([Pronouns: Agreement and Reference](http://www.buowl.boun.edu.tr/students/grammar/writing%20guides/pronouns.htm)